# How do I include JavaScript in a Meteor package so that it's not transformed in the client?

Tags: javascript, meteor, package, minify

How do I include client JavaScript files in a Meteor (as of 0.9.3) [package](http://docs.meteor.com/#writingpackages), in such a way that they do not get transformed (i.e., minified, wrapped) by Meteor when delivered to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have a package called `mypackage` and an asset called `myscript.js`. Your `package.js` could look something like this:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: 'This works!'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.2');
  api.addAssets('myscript.js', 'client');
});
```

With [addAssets](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/PackageAPI-addAssets), the file will not be transformed/compiled. In this case, `myscript.js` would be available to the client via this path:

`/packages/mypackage/myscript.js`

Comment: The JavaScript still gets wrapped, and when I run Meteor in production mode, the file is bundled (at least the .js file isn't present).

Comment: Neither of these things appear to be the case in the test project I'm using. Did you create the package, and do `meteor add`, etc.?

Comment: I created the package in packages/<package> and added it with `meteor add <package>`. Are you testing with `meteor run --production`?

Comment: Yes. I created a repo for you to test with [here](https://github.com/dweldon/asset-test). Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: OK thanks, must get back to you since it's bed time and I'm traveling tomorrow.

Comment: I thought it is `{bare:true}`?

Comment: @aknuds1 Did you get this to work? I'd like to remove that repo.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Oops, didn't get around to it yet. Had laser on one eye in the meantime, so I'm just starting to function again. Will try tomorrow.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Thanks, you can delete the repo.

Comment: Looks like you're right; although there is a bundled representation of the package, it's practically empty so it doesn't matter. The original JavaScript is available as /packages/<package>/<script> like you say.

Comment: Updated for meteor 1.2.